# SQL query returning Too Few Parameters

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an access database that I am attempting to reference a SQL query

```
  Set dba = CurrentDb

  SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_NewHireStep WHERE Location = '" & Site & "' AND E-Verified = TRUE "

  Set rst = dba.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Keeps giving me a Too few parameters error. In SQL it works great. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After SQL, type `Debug.Print SQL` and see if you're getting the SQL statement you're expecting

Comment: I solved it, actually it didn't like the dash in my field name, changed that and it worked great.

Comment: This is not an off-topic question, it is an access problem that SQL didn't like the answer given. When you create tables in Access you can potentially use many different characters to create a table name. However, when those tables are then converted to SQL and a SQL statement is used to pull the data, you many not be able to use those unique characters. READ QUESTION BEFORE YOU CLOSE IT AS OFF-TOPIC! Who is able to decide if this isn't helpful to someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyphen, `-`, is an [Access reserved symbol](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe#__toc272229039).  If you want to use it in a field or table name, then you must always put that field or table name inside square brackets when you reference it.  For example,

```
SQL = " SELECT * FROM tbl_NewHireStep " & _
      " WHERE Location = '" & Site & "' AND [E-Verified] = TRUE "
```

It's far better to avoid using reserved words and symbols in the first place.  Several years ago, Allen Browne compiled a list of [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  I'm not sure how current the list is, but it is a great reference when creating new database schemas.